# Recorrer un Array bajo una condición

Tags: python, array, numpy

tengo un problema con recorrer un array bajo una condición.
Realicé la multiplicación de matrices:

```
materiales = np.multiply(productos, cantidades)
materiales = np.sum(materiales, axis=1)
array([15., 11.])
```

Luego, me dan un costo:

```
costos = np.array([5.0, 3.0])
```

Que al multiplicarlo, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
costos_pedido = np.multiply(costos, materiales)
costos_pedido
array([75., 33.])
```

Tengo una variable "lote", que vale:

```
lote=0.2
```

Lo que implica que si algun elemento del array de materiales es >=15, se le debe aplicar un descuento del 20% (0.2 como lo indica lote) a su correspondiente en el array de costo.

Intento hacer esta solución:

```
for i in materiales:
  if materiales>=15:
    costos[i] = [i]*(1-0.2)
```

y obtengo error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
Me pueden ayudar por favor.

Es de resaltar que si se aplica el descuento, el array de costo_pedido va a cambiar de valor.

Comment: La variable `i` toma el valor de cada uno de los elementos y por eso te da error, ya que no es correcto hacer `costos[i]`. Por cierto esta condición ` if materiales>=15` no tiene ucho sentido, puesto que `materiales` es un array y no un elemento

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar si algún elemento del array es >= 15 recorriéndolo debes poner la **i** en el condicional del for, tal que así:

```
for i in materiales:
  if i >= 15:
    costos = i*(1-0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de corregirlo puede ser:

```
for i  in range(materiales.size):
    if materiales[i]>=15:
        costo[i] = costo[i]*(1-0.2)
```

Comment: El único posible *error* que podría ocurrir es que el tamaño de las listas sean diferentes, pero es muy buena opción.